# Get specific index from map with list of lists as value

Tags: java, groovy

I cant figure how to do the following in java

In groovy, if I want to iterate over a map and inside that map the value is a list of lists. then get a specific index from a list of lists i.e. the following code will work

```
def total = value.collect { it.get(0) }*.toInteger().sum()
```

I read all lists with a specific index using the spread operator and convert all retrieved data to an integer and get the sum.

How do to this in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java 8 stream API to iterate over outer list and fetch specific index form inner list. And then use mapToInt and sum function to retrieve required output.

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
int key = 8;
int index = 0;
int sum = map.get(key).stream().mapToInt(internalList -> internalList.get(index)).sum();
```

For you it would look something like this.

```
int total = value.stream().mapToInt(internalList-> internalList.get(index)).sum();
```